# Context free languages

Tags: context-free-grammar

The computer science class im in has us doing context free grammars.
I think I understand how they work but Im not sure.
Can someone tell me if Im doing these correctly or if im missing something in these?
I dont necessarially want straight answers to the questions but I would like to know if im doing these correctly or if I need to account for something else.

```
{0^2n 1^3n | n in the set of natural numbers}
 my answer: S-> 00S111 | Lambda
```

for this one im assuming that this will recursively add 00 and 111 to the string and that if it doesnt add the S then it will add the lambda which would close the string leaving just 0's and 1's

The other one is

```
{0^n 1^n | N in the set of natural numbers} 
my answer: S -> 0S1 | A
           A -> 0S1 | lambda
```

again lambda would close the string.

so are these correct or am I missing something?

edit: question 1 should have 1^3n not 1^n

Comment: I do not see why you would need `A` in the second example. Also, in the first one, the number of `0` and `1` produced do not match what I understand is being described (that is, a string of `2n` 0s followed by `n` 1s). Anyway the general idea is correct.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake on the first one. For the second one the examples we are given look like {01 0011 010011} so I have the A there as a second case in which it picks and starts again.
would it work better to change it so A has the option of S or 
Lambda to make it start again?
    
    so instead something like this
S-> 0s1 | s | lambda  ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a commentary but I need more space...

For the second example (as described in the comment), your grammar does not work.

Your grammar will create a string of `n` 0s followed by `n` 1s. Nothing more, nothing else.

You would need some production that allows you to add values **after** the current production. If I were to write `0^n 1^n 2^x`, I would use

```
  S -> AB 
  A -> 0A1 | lambda 
  B -> 2B | lambda
```

Does that help?

(*) In reality after or before are just relative terms, but we usually read it in that order (to the right means later).